# MODIS - MOD11A1 Data not available <2018 using the MODIS package (R)?

Tags: r, modis, time-series

I'm using the MODIS package to download MOD11A1 data, I'm looking for a timeseries from 2016 to 2020, which is well within the temporal range of the data. However, when I try downloading the data using the code below:

```
tfs = runGdal(job = "MODIS_Time_Series",
              product = "MOD11A1",
              begin = "2016.01.01", end = "2020.12.31",
              extent = getT, outDirPath = dir)
```

Only downloads 2018 onwards work. I've tried splitting it up by downloading by year, but again, downloads appear to stop working once I try to download anything before 2018.01.01.

Answer (score 1):

This MOD11A1 product has 2 versions (v006 and v061). Check if the tiles you are trying to download are available on the [DataPool](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/data-pool/).

You can also try pymodis if you are willing to work with Python.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/212957)

Comment: @Vince Without being able to comment, it is difficult to understand the source of the problem without further clarification. However, I rephrased the answer.